# The meaning and usage of "не то чтобы"

Tags: словоупотребление

> Они **не то чтобы** открыть, а даже сдвинуть его с места не могут.

I'm familiar with the expression "Не то чтобы" -- in the sense of "Not that ..." -- placed at the beginning of a subordinate clause, but I assume we are looking at a different meaning here, given its position. Is it close in meaning to "мало того, что ..."?

Comment: The meaning is equivalent to the English "let alone": "They can't even move it, let alone open it".

Comment: @mustaccio Hi. When you say "can't A, let alone B" in English, the negation in B is even stronger, indicating that B is even more unlikely to happen than A. Does the same go for this Russian sentence with “не то чтобы”? It seems to me as if it's the other way around, given the word "даже" in the second half: "They can't open it, let alone move it".

Comment: I understand what "let alone" means, and yes, “не то чтобы” has the same meaning.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Is "открыть" negated by "**не** то чтобы" or "**не** могут"?

Comment: "не то чтобы"..

Comment: What does **его** refer to? Could you give us more context?

Comment: @SergeySlepov Hi. They were talking about an extremely heavy safe.

Comment: by opening the safe did they mean opening it without knowing the code essentially meaning breaking into it?

Comment: The adverb "даже" here shifts the meaning of "Не то чтобы" from "Not that" or "Not exactly" to "Not even" or "Not only".

Comment: i'm sorry i was wrong initially with regard to the *let alone* expression, it truly necessitates reversal of the clauses, and so i'm in agreement with  *mustaccio*, i only think that translation through the use of *let alone* isn't the most elegant one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First there's a need to clarify the accurate wording of the construction, which should be

> Они **не то что** открыть, а даже сдвинуть его с места не могут

[**не то чтобы**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B) has different meaning, namely  **`not exactly/quite`**  and  **`it's not that`**

> употребляется при выражении неопределённости оценки признака или
>   действия

> И **не то чтобы** да, и **не то чтобы** нет - ***Not exactly*** 'yes' and **not exactly** 'no' either
>
> **Не то чтобы** все, но многие - ***Not exactly*** everyone, but many
>
> Моря **не то чтобы** нет — оно далеко и очень мелкое - ***It's not that*** there's no sea, **but it's** far away and very shallow.
>
> Сейф **не то чтобы** тяжёлый, **просто** громоздкий - ***It's not that*** the safe is heavy/The safe is **not exactly** heavy, **just** bulky
>
> Cейф **не то чтобы** тяжёлый, **но** сдвинуть его с места они (всё равно) не могут - ***It's not that*** the safe is heavy, **but** they **still** can't move it

Native speakers seem to confuse the two.

Now the phrase in question in its rectified form

> Они **не то что** открыть, а даже сдвинуть его с места не могут

is translated as

> Not only can't they open it, even budge it they can't

If a safe is protected by a code, obviously opening it without knowing the code is a much harder task than moving it, therefore inability to move it is more striking due to being less likely to happen and this is what gets the syntactic emphasis.

Synonymous Russian constructions are

> Они **мало того, что** открыть его не могут, они не могут его **даже**
>   с места сдвинуть.
>
> **Мало того, что** они его не могут открыть, **так** они его **ещё и** с места сдвинуть не могут.

The adverb **мало** signifies that the content of the 1st clause is only a part of the problem, while the brunt of the problem is introduced with the adverbs **даже** and **ещё** in the 2nd clause.

---

**не то, что** always fashions exacerbation, aggravation

> Она **не то, что** маленькая, она микроскопическая - *Not only it's small, it's microscopic*
>
> Я ему **не то, что** сказал, я ему это в ухо проорал - *Not only i told him so, i shouted this into his ear*

compare with the connotation of reservation or abatement created by **не то чтобы** (essentially the opposite of the one created by *не то, что*)

> Она **не то чтобы** маленькая, но всё равно по размеру не годится - *It's not exactly small, but still doesn't meet the size*
>
> Я ему **не то чтобы** сказал, а так, намекнул - *It's not that i told him so, just hinted*

Comment: Good start but then it goes a bit off. You imply a person speaking out that phrase is making a mistake. But he is not, he was pronouncing "Они не то что бы открыть, а даже...." - granted both "что бы" and "чтобы" sound the same exactly, and that is the root of TS'es confusion, he heard correct phrase but wrote it down a bit off. So, I think it was great to start without "бы" at all to put a "normative" example first, but then "что бы" and "что б" had to be added afterwards as optional legit variants.

Comment: considering the idea of the entire sentence i don't see how **чтобы** could be correct or idiomatic, ordinary native speakers often don't observe these nuances or probably are simply unaware of their existence... in correct usage **не то чтобы** fashions reservation or contrast and not exacerbation as **не то, что**, here's an example of proper use of ***не то чтобы*** - ***"Они не то чтобы не могут его открыть, просто ленятся"***, also **не то чтобы** seems to never be followed by **даже** in subordinate clause

Comment: not "чтобы" but "что бы" - you have to account that what was *written* by Con is not necessarily was what he heard *spoken* actually

Comment: for the purpose of that sentence **бы** is redundant regardless of whether it's spelled jointly or severally

Comment: Sure, it is redundant, but it is legit if the narrator wants it. You say that there is no legit phrase variant with "бы" sound, and there actually exists legit, if redundant, way to write it down. Also, redundancy is part of many figures of speech.

Comment: that problem is that it creates semantic ambiguity due to making the construction sound identical to a construction having essentially opposite meaning... to put it bluntly you can't for example insert **бы** and claim that the sentence doesn't sound conditional, everything has its purpose, it's OK when constructions are synonymous, in this case however they're not

Comment: It does [create ambiguity]. But human language created by evolution is not mathematical language created by purposeful design. Would it be - there would be no play on words (double entendre), for example.

Answer (score 3):

The closest phrase in English would be something like "**Not only couldn't they** open it - they failed even to move it".

The other similar Russian phrase worth to know is "что там", like in:

> Что там открыть - они сдвинуть с места его не могут!

Answer (score 2):

The correct translation would be:

- They can't even *move* it, let alone opening it.

Opening is perceived as a more difficult task than moving.

Comment: after some deliberation i do concede your translation is accurate

Comment: Considering its word order, can I see "не то чтобы открыть" as a parenthetical phrase: "They -- **never mind / let alone opening it** -- can't even move it"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens, In English, "let alone opening it" probably can be seen as a parenthetical phrase. In Russian, the two verbs governed by могут (открыть and сдвинуть) are peer members joined by the conjunction "не то что ..., а даже ..." One could use some other conjunction, e.g. "ни ..., ни ...": Они ни открыть, ни даже сдвинуть его не могут.

Comment: As БаянКупи-ка has mentioned, do you think "не то чтобы открыть" is an error here?

Comment: It didn't strike me as an error at first glance but I agree that что sounds more correct in this context.